# Google Charts wont take js variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-visualization

I'm integrating a line chart from google, and I'm trying to add variable values, however when I change the numeric values for the chart to a js variable it evaluates to 0.

JS:

```
 import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts'


   export default {
    name: 'linegraph',
    props: ['dates', 'stats'],
    data() {
      return {

            test: 5, 
            items: {

            },
          chartData: [
            ['Date', 'Items Sold'],
            [this.dates.monday, 1],
            [this.dates.tuesday, 50],
            [this.dates.wednesday, 3],
            [this.dates.thursday, 2],
            [this.dates.friday, 6],
            [this.dates.saturday, 8],
            [this.dates.sunday, parseInt(this.test)]
          ],
          chartOptions: {
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                animation: {
                  duration: 1000,
                  easing: 'inAndOut',
                  startup: true
                },
                colors: ['#74D698'],
            }
        } 
    },
```

I've tried leaving the variable as it is, wrapping it in parseFloat, parseInt, number() etc. Nothing seems to be working and its not erroring either. Any help would be fantastic! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, If you're in a vue component, you need to declare the variables outside of the export function in their own var.